# req.session.user is deleted while user is active

Tags: node.js, passport.js, node-redis

I set the session timeout to 30 minutes.  While I am still active, `req.session.user` is deleted after 30 minutes.  However, the session is still alive.  Here's my config (i'm using express-session and passport.js):

```
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({client: <my client>, disableTTL: true}),
    secret: <some_secret>,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {maxAge: 1800000}
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Are these serializer/deserializer needed?
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
```

In login:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
        ...
        if (user) {
            req.session.user = {email: req.body.username};
        }
        next();
    })(req, res);
});
```

The verify code is like this:

```
isLoggedIn() {
    if (req.session && req.session.user) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I set the `req.session.user` to some object after I successfully logged in.

So, after 30 minutes, `req.session.user` is deleted, but `req.session` is still there and keeps on incrementing the expiry date since I am still actively working on the page.

Why is `req.session.user` deleted after 30 minutes?  I thought passport rides on the session by express?

*** UPDATE ***
At first, I thought the expiry is incrementing, but it's not.  Previously, I set `resave: false`.  Then when I log the session, the expiry is always the same:

```
Session {
    cookie:
         { path: '/', _expires: <some date>.... }
    user:
         { email: <the one i set before>, sessionId: <some id> } }
```

Then after 30 minutes, the user is deleted.  Only at this point, the expiry begins incrementing.

```
Session {
    cookie:
         { path: '/', _expires: <some date>.... }
```

Then I read something about the `touch` method that express-session calls. The documentation said that if the store implements this `touch` method, then it's ok to set the `resave: false`.  So, thinking that redis may not be implementing this method, I tried setting `resave: true`.  Then when I log the session, I noticed that the expiry is now incrementing, compared to the previous that it only increments after user is deleted.  However, after 30 minutes, again the user key is deleted.

Then with niry's suggestion, I set the `disableTTL: true`.  Again, the same thing happened.

In redis, I try to mget the key.  Before the 30 minutes end, the expiry in redis is incrementing:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> mget sess:<some id>
```

1) "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":1800000,\"expires\":\"2018-11-15T06:04:26.994Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"user\":{\"email\":\"test@email.com\",\"sessionId\":\"some session id\"}}"

Then after 30 minutes, I looked at redis, the session key is still there but it stopped incrementing the expiry.  While, req.session still increments the expiry but with the user property deleted.

Comment: Please post the redis options. I suspect you set the expiration on the data.

Comment: I didn't set any expiration on Redis. In the options i only provide the client to connect to. Besides, even when i encountered the timeout, the session id remains in redis.

Comment: Just to clarify, with "encountered the timeout", I mean the req.session.user that I set got deleted after 30 minutes of still being active.  I'm thinking there's something going on with passport, maybe, i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is req.session.user deleted after 30 minutes?

Because the `maxAge` option of cookie is set to `1800000` ms which is 30 minutes. So the browser ( or whatever client you are using ) will delete the cookie after 30 minutes.

A session is some information you want to persist over subsequent requests. Generally, a session has an ID(sessionID) and associated payload. When you do `req.session = { ... }`, the `express-session` middleware would take the object, generate an ID and save it in the `store` you specified. (`RedisStore` in your case). So now your "database" has the mapping of `sessionID` and the `payload`.

Cookies are something that once sent from the server, they would be forwarded every-time to that server (to that domain) for each subsequent request until they are expired. Note that once the cookie is received, it is the client's job to manage it. The generated `sessionID` along with the signature is sent to the client in the cookie.

Once the cookie is saved on your client. It will forwarded with the next request.
When your `express-session` middleware sees the cookie, it extracts the `sessionID` from the cookie, and try to look for the corresponding payload in the `store` (`RedisStore` in your case). The payload is then set to `req.session` along with other information.

Once the expiry time is reached, the client will delete the cookie. Thus, request from that client would not have the cookie. Because the cookie is not there, the `express-session` will not be able to set the `req.session` and you would think that the user is logged out. Note that, the store still contains the `sessionID, payload` mapping which will be deleted according to `ttl` config of `store`.

---

I think the confusion arose in the first place is because of `session.cookie` field. `session.cookie` will always be there because of the `express-session` middleware.

If you want to see the actual cookies received in the request, try [`cookie-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) middleware.

---

I am attaching sample code to tinker. The `set-cookie` endpoint will set the cookie which expires in 20 seconds. `get-cookie` endpoint will get the `cookie` and `session` data.

Hope this will help!

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const FileStore = require("session-file-store")(session);
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
    session({
        secret: "top secret!",
        resave: false,
        rolling: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 20 * 1000
        },
        name: "demo",
        store: new FileStore({
            path: path.join(__dirname, "../sessions"),
            retries: 1,
            fileExtension: ".json"
        })
    })
);

app.use("/set-cookie", (req, res) => {
    req.session.payload = { foo: "bar", timestamp: new Date().toISOString() };
    res.json({ message: "done" });
});

app.use("/get-cookie", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        sessionID: req.sessionID,
        session: req.session,
        cookies: req.cookies,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString()
    });
});

app.listen(3000, err => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("demo app listening on port 3000");
});
```

---

**UPDATE**
Based on the comments, what you are looking for the [`rolling`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#rolling) option. Once you set the `rolling: true` in `express-session`, the session will be updated for every request. And user will be logged out after `maxAge` IDEAL time.

I have updated the code.

Comment: Sorry but I got more confused.  I think I understand the part of session cookie between the client and the server.  The thing is, the user is still active and the expiry time is incrementing.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "the user is still active"?. As I said, the expiry time is the time when the cookie would expire if it is set in that request

Comment: So, you would always see `expires at = current time + maxAge ` no matter the cookie is actually set or not. Try it out

Comment: My goal is when user becomes idle for 30 minutes, the session will expire.  So when the user try to call an api, i'll throw an error since his session is already expired.  But since the user is still activly calling the api within 30 minutes, i am expecting the session expiry will increment.  For example, the user has been idle for 5 minutes, so the remaining time before session expires is 25 minutes.  Then user calls an api and the expiry time resets to 30 minutes.  Looking at redis and req.session, it seems incrementing while user is active which is what i expect.

Comment: Ahh alright now I understand it properly. I would update the answer accordingly, meanwhile, you might want to update the question with that details too!

Comment: Man I have to give this to you.  You're right, it's the rolling thingy. I just don't get why this is default to false.  I thought it's a common thing to reset expiry when user is active.  Anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Happy I was able to help!, Also, It is by default `false` to reduce db operations. Think about it, each request mean at least one query to db. Based on the DB, it might not be feasible. The common practise I see is to set `maxAge` in days (30 days) and `rolling: false`.